# Issue with runnable jar file with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

(I see that this question was asked a couple of times a few years back, I tried the suggested methods but they aren't working for me).

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.1a).
Java version is 9.0.1

As an exercise, I just coded a very simple guessing game application (with GUI) from a very recent (2017) Java book from a well known publisher. The app runs smoothly from Eclipse.

Then I wanted to create a runnable JAR file, with file -> export -> java -> runnable JAR file. I then entered those apparently obvious *launch configuration* and *export destination* details, but when I clicked on finish it says "JAR creation failed" (details: No resources selected. JAR export finished with problems. Could not find main method for given launch configuration)

Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you specifying the main class in META-INF file also the dependencies? Extract and have a look

Comment: Where is located the META-INF file in my project? From the export wizard I cannot do more than what I did.

Comment: Extract the runnable jar and see

Comment: Runnable jar is not extracting, "JAR creation failed".

Comment: During runnable jar creation there is a option to specify the META-INF folder from eclipse

Comment: There is no mention of META-INF folder in the extract wizard here

Comment: You mean I try to export as JAR file? No runnable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47280948/753468

Comment: Have u tried this?

Comment: I tried a few of these but didn't work. I have no idea on what to do

Comment: 1. Try clean and build
2. Try downgrading jdk version

Comment: I tried everything but it doesn't work, I also created a manifest.mf file with the class info but I am reluctant to downgrade to jdk 8 just for this issue... thanks anyway.